# How to scroll the screen with the player in python turtle

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics, tkinter-canvas, python-turtle

I'm quite new to python. I have spent most of my time coding in turtle and I am now able to code simple games like space invaders. What I'm wondering is how I scroll the screen along with my player. What I mean is that if I were to make a map with several rooms I would like the screen to show different rooms by moving to where they have been drawn on the map. I don't really understand how tkinter works so please if anyone here can explain without using Tkinter or link a detailed video I would greatly appreciate it.

what I'm trying to do is draw a map with a pen in a turtle and then move the screen along the map instead of moving the turtle along the screen and having to show the whole map in 1 image.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: My answer to [How do I get the Turtle canvas screen to move with a Turtle module?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55895481/5771269) might be of help to you.